# Editando dinamicamente um variável no android

Tags: java, android

Olá, tenho uma Activity que tem alguns campos de TextView e logo a baixo estou colocando alguns EditText para que seu eu queira alterar estes campos eu insiro os dados e clico no botão e ele automaticamente vai la e altera estas TextViews para mim porem não estou conseguindo encontrar algo do tipo na net...

Portanto fiz alguma coisa porem não da certo:

Código da Activity

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/App_Theme_Meals_Background"
tools:context="meals.com.meals.activity.Activity.PerfilActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Nome"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewNome" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewTelefone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Telefone"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewEmail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNumeroCartao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="NumeroCartão"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextViewTelefone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CodCartaoPerfil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Cod Cartão"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="183dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Alterar Casdastro"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.414" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNomePerfil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,LabelFor,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="274dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMailPerfil"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="338dp"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTelefone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="399dp"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCartãoPerfil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,LabelFor,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCodCartaoPerfil"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="251dp"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor,MissingConstraints" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAlterarPerfil"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@color/App_Theme_Meals_colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="Alterar Perfil"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Não sei pq não deu para colocar o código todo portanto segue uma imagem da Activity (Logo abaixo do Alterar perfil é os EditText que quero setar eles iguais com o TextView)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora segue minha tentativa de código

public class PerfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference firebase;
private TextView Nome;
private TextView Email;
private TextView telefone;
private TextView NumeroCartão;
private TextView CodCard;
private EditText EditName;
private EditText EditEmail;
private EditText EditTelefone;
private EditText EditCartao;
private EditText EditCodCartao;
private Button Alterar;

public Editable nome = "Victor Roja Tavoni";
public Editable email = "victortavoni@uol.com.br";
public Editable Telefone = "+5519997749701";
public Editable Cartão = "0000000000000000";
public Editable codCard = "123";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

    Nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
    Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    telefone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTelefone);
    NumeroCartão = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNumeroCartao);
    CodCard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CodCartaoPerfil);
    EditName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomePerfil);
    EditEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMailPerfil);
    EditTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefone);
    EditCartao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCartãoPerfil);
    EditCodCartao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCodCartaoPerfil);
    Alterar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAlterarPerfil);


    nome = "Victor Roja Tavoni";
    email = "victortavoni@uol.com.br";
    Telefone = "+5519997749701";
    Cartão = "0000000000000000";
    codCard = "123";



    Nome.setText("Nome: " + nome);
    Email.setText("Email: " + email);
    telefone.setText("Telefone: " + Telefone);
    NumeroCartão.setText("Numero Cartão: " + Cartão);
    CodCard.setText("Cod. Cartão: "+codCard);

    Alterar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nome = EditName.getText();
            email = EditEmail.getText();
            Telefone = EditTelefone.getText();
            Cartão = EditCartao.getText();
            CodCard = EditCodCartao.getText();
        }
    });





}
```

}